# Android Activity extends AlertDialog

Tags: android, extends, android-alertdialog

I have an activity whose only purpose is to launch an AlertDialog. My issue is that I cannot figure out what to have the activity extend so that the dialog opens on top of whatever the user has open. Currently, it opens a blank layout behind it with `extends Activity`. Everything else I try fills the activity with errors. Do any of you wonderful internet people know what I can do to make it so that only the alertDialog opens when the activity is triggered?

Comment: "an activity whose only purpose is to launch an AlertDialog", this doesn't make any sense to me, please provide more explanation regarding to you requirement.

Comment: All the activity does is call an AlertDialog. That's the only thing I intend for it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an own style. Create (if you don't yet have it) a file `styles.xml` in `res\values\`, and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Dialog.NoTitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, set this style as the `android:theme`:

```
<activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Dialog.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be popping up an alert dialog and should be more sensitive to your users. Consider using notifications: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Notifications are also the recommended intermediary when you want to launch an activity following your background tasks.

Comment: The AlertDialog comes up when the user clicks on a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the `AlertDialog` inside of a `Service` (i.e. `class MyAlertService extends Service`) and then launch that service instead of a whole `Activity`.

[This site](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) has great examples of using your own `Service`. In your case, you would simply put your alert dialog code in the `onStart` method of the `Service` class.